# localStorage SET for just one day

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, popup

I need to put up a pop up. It will be updated daily, so the pop up needs to show every day on page load if a user comes to the website, (new users and even users that have visited before) but if the user clicks the notice away, it needs to stay hidden for 24 hours, before resetting. I've written this code but can't get it to compare itself with the last time it was shown, using localStorage.

```
  var modal = document.querySelector(".opening-modal");
  var close = document.getElementById("pageDiv");
  var element = document.getElementById("pageDiv");

    function popupShown() {
        if (!localStorage.getItem('showPopup')) { //check if popup has already been shown, if not then proceed
            localStorage.setItem('showPopup', 'true'); // Set the flag in localStorage
            element.classList.add("show-modal");
        }
    }
    function closeModal() {
        element.classList.add("hide-modal");
    }
    window.setTimeout(popupShown, 1500);
    window.addEventListener("click", closeModal);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd give each modal an ID (ascending) and store the ID of the last modal the user dismissed. That way, if the modal doesn't change for 48 hours instead of 24, the user isn't shown the modal again.

```
var popupId = 42; // This is the number that changes when the content changes
if (+localStorage.dismissedPopup !== popupId) {
    // Either the user has never dismissed one of these, or it's not the most recent one
    window.setTimeout(popupShown, 1500);
}
function closeModal() {
    element.classList.add("hide-modal");
    // Remember the ID of the most recent modal the user dismissed
    localStorage.dismissedPopup = popupId;
}
```

If you want to drive this from the HTML, the ID can come from a `data-*` attribute:

```html
<div id="pageDiv" data-popup-id="42">An important update about...</div>
```

Then:

```js
var popupId = +element.getAttribute("data-popup-id");
```

---

But if you want it to be time-based, store the time it was last dismissed:

```
if (!localStorage.lastPopupDismissed ||
    (Date.now() - localStorage.lastPopupDismissed) > (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))) {
    window.setTimeout(popupShown, 1500);
}
function closeModal() {
    element.classList.add("hide-modal");
    // Remember the ID of the most recent modal the user dismissed
    localStorage.lastPopupDismissed = Date.now();
}
```

Comment: This will be added to my custom Wordpress theme for the client to update the text, so I don't want them to have to access the javascript. Ideally I just want the local storage to compare with last set and show again if over 24 hours has elapsed.

Comment: @DanG - The second one above will do that. (We could also compare the text rather than an ID in the first one.)